# Difference between Session and Connection in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, session, database-connection

In case of temporary tables, we see that they are connection dependent. I mean that tables created in one connection is only available to that connection and automatically dropped when the connection is lost or destroyed.

What is the difference between connection and session in SQL Server?

Comment: This has already been asked and answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/what-is-the-difference-between-a-connection-and-a-session

Comment: and here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3975aea5-bc92-424a-a1c0-75c6e5e2f8a6/what-is-the-differencs-between-sessions-and-connections-in-sqlserver?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score 19):

A Connection is Physical Communication Channel and Session is a state of information exchange. A Connection may have multiple sessions.

> The connection is the physical communication channel between SQL
> Server and the application: the TCP socket, the named pipe, the shared
> memory region. The session in SQL Server corresponds to the Wikipedia
> definition of a [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29): a semi-permanent container of state for
> an information exchange. In other words the sessions stores settings
> like cache of your login information, current transaction isolation
> level, [session level `SET` values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) etc etc.
>
> Normally there is one session on each connection, but there could be
> multiple session on a single connection ([Multiple Active Result
> Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx), MARS) and there are sessions that have no connection ([SSB
> activated procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171585.aspx), [system sessions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/01/10/how-it-works-system-sessions.aspx)). There are also
> connections w/o sessions, namely connections used for non-TDS
> purposes, like database mirroring
> [`sys.dm_db_mirroring_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189796.aspx) or Service Broker connections
> [`sys.dm_broker_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189490.aspx).

I got the answer from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/what-is-the-difference-between-a-connection-and-a-session/13700#13700)

Comment: Did you copy that from [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13700/4626)?

Comment: Yes, I got the reference from the same link, I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: So how do I end up with multiple sessions for a single connection?

select count(*) from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id = 62

Result = 3

Comment: What exactly is *"physical"* about the communication channel? TCP sockets are not physical.

Answer (score 15):

**common concepts that get used with SQL Server thread management and scheduling :**

> **Sessions** – when the client application connects to SQL Server the two sides establish a “session” on which to exchange information. Strictly speaking a session is not the same as the underlying physical connection, it is a SQL Server logical representation of a connection. But for practical purposes, you can think of this as being a connection (session =~ connection). See sys.dm_exec_sessions. This is the old SPID that existed in SQL Server 2000 and earlier. You may sometimes notice a single session repeating multiple times in a DMV output. This happens because of parallel queries. A parallel query uses the same session to communicate with the client, but on the SQL Server side multiple worker (threads) are assigned to service this request. So if you see multiple rows with the same session ID, know that the query request is being serviced by multiple threads.

```
-
```

> **Connections** – this is the actual physical connection established at the lower protocol level with all of its characteristics sys.dm_exec_connections . There is a 1:1 mapping between a Session and a Connection.

Answer (score 2):

**Connection** is ***the relationship*** between a client and a SQL Server database.

**Session** is ***the period of time*** between a client logging in (connecting to) a SQL Server database and the client logging out (exiting) the SQL Server database.

Comment: The period or what happens during that period?

Comment: @HeneyEcker.. when you say "a client".... does this mean no other client from another computer can use the same connection String to connect to that database?