# If more than one transactions are running at a time, do they have to belong to different connections?

Tags: postgresql

Can a connection to postgresql server have more than one transactions running at a time?

If more than one transactions are running at a time, do they have to belong to different connections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single connection creates a single session. A session can have a single transaction. So, no.

Comment: Thanks. Are "session" and "connection" the same concepts and represented in the same way in postgresql?

Comment: More or less, yeah. Technically you can have a (TCP) connection without a database session, but in your context they’re to be used interchangeably.

Comment: in SQL Server, a connection can have multiple sessions, does it mean that a connection can have multiple concurrently running transactions?  Does a session only have one transaction too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199173/difference-between-session-and-connection-in-sql-server

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have the same question. One service may handle workload for different users and for each user it must make it within a transaction. So one service would only have N open connection but can serve M users. So the question if one connection can multiplex many transactions stands.